# Intersection of translates of theta divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be a principally polarized abelian surface, and $\Gamma \subset A$ a finite subgroup. Denote by $\Theta$ a symmetric theta divisor in $A$. Is it always true that for any $g_1, g_2 \in \Gamma$ the intersection $\Theta \cap \Theta_{g_1} \cap \Theta_{g_2}$ is empty? (Here, $\Theta_g$ denotes the translate of $\Theta$ by $g$).

If this is true, could you explain why? If not, is the locus of principally polarized abelian surfaces for which the above claim fails a divisor in the moduli space?

Comment: You should specify that $g_1$ and $g_2$ are distinct and not equal to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

This is always false. Suppose your $A$ is irreducible, i.e. is the Jacobian of a genus 2 curve $C$. Let $p,q,r$ be Weierstrass points of $C$. Take $\Theta =C-p$, 
 $g_1=p-q$ and $g_2=p-r$. Then $\Theta \cap \Theta_{g_1} \cap \Theta_{g_2}$ contains $0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In your counterexample, both $g_1$ and $g_2$ have order $2$. Are there similar counterexamples in the case where $\Gamma$ contains no element of order $2$?

Comment: Similar, no. The point is that torsion points of order $>2$ are much harder to write down. I would be tempted to guess that such counterexamples do not exist for a *generic* curve, but that would probably be very hard to prove.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you could also look at Proposition 3.3 in
http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2003-355-08/S0002-9947-03-03303-8/S0002-9947-03-03303-8.pdf

Comment: How is it relevant?

Comment: the relevance is the degree of self intersection. The intersection of three algebraically equivalent divisors on a surface is expected to be zero, if they are general enough. using translates, it is subtle and this is well-know problem in diophantine geometry, see works of daniel Bertrand.